# jQuery modal pop up similar in behaviour to the confirm and alert dialogues

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I need a custom jquery modal dialog which can host any content and comes out of the browser (if the browser is small). It should be possible to move the dialog anywhere outside the browser like alert and confirm dialogues.

All the dialogues I have seen are restricted to the browser, however the confirm navigation dialogue behaviour is what I need. Is it possible to achieve??

Comment: You want the modal window to be positioned centrally or it should over flow the browser's viewport (which is not possible anyway)?

Comment: You [almost] can't get a blocking modal with a real popup - stick with inner HTML solutions. Nevertheless, popups, alerts and confirm boxes should be avoided.

Comment: i too thought it wasnt possible, but when i saw the behaviour of alerts which can be dragged even outside browser's viewport i was hopeful.. basically my browser window will be very small horizontally, n i want to show the user a modal form(on some button click) which is visible fully......

Answer (score 1):

Did you try window.open(...) ? 
Read http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: +1: the only feasible idea. good one :) please dont use [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) as reference. wont this do? [winow.open| MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open)